# Finding the average array from multiple 2d arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm analyzing car location data and need to find the average "snapshot". I used python to generate a few dozen 2d csv's that contain car plates and their longitude/latitude. Each csv is between 7000-15000 in length. How can I condense their information into one 2d array that would contain the average number of cars with the average location?

The best way to visualize what I mean is to find the average of a several number of scatterplots. I tried using Excel to generate scatterplots (maps) to see if I could overlay them and get the average from them. I couldn't figure out what to do (or to search)

I'm looking to get an output that would most likely be a dataframe. It's length would be the average number of cars, each line corresponding to a specific car and would have an estimated longitude/latitude placement for that car.

Comment: It's possible that you want a [histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html#numpy.histogramdd)

Comment: Note that latitude/longitude are not rectangular coordinates, so a histogram over lat longs is probably only a good representation for a small-ish area